# How to extract records which have a mix of values in a specific field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running SQL Server 2012 and I have the following table called `StayDateInfo`.
An extract of this table is given below:

```
ResaID    StayDate    RoomCat
100       2018-03-01   STD
100       2018-03-02   STD
100       2018-03-03   STD
101       2018-04-15   STD
101       2018-04-16   STD
101       2018-04-17   DLX
101       2018-04-18   DLX
```

This table holds around 2 million rows.

I need to extract all 3 columns from that table where the `RoomCat` values by `ResaID` are NOT the same for each `StayDate`.

In the extract above, `ResaID` 101 will need to be in the output as it has a mix of values (STD and DLX) for its `RoomCat`.

How do I write my `T-SQ`L query to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure 101 should be in output because `StayDate` is different for each record ?

Comment: Yes. Basically, I need all ResaIDs which contain more than one type of RoomCat, irrespective of StayDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your actual table name with `@xyz` in below solution.

Input Data for my testing -

```
declare @xyz table (ResaID    int, StayDate    date, RoomCat varchar(10))

insert into @xyz
select 100       ,'2018-03-01',   'STD' union all
select 100       ,'2018-03-02',   'STD' union all
select 100       ,'2018-03-03',   'STD' union all
select 101       ,'2018-04-15',   'STD' union all
select 101       ,'2018-04-16',   'STD' union all
select 101       ,'2018-04-17',   'DLX' union all
select 101       ,'2018-04-18',   'DLX'
```

Solution -

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
@xyz AS X
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ResaID FROM @xyz GROUP BY ResaID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT RoomCat) > 1
    ) AS Y ON Y.ResaID = X.ResaID
```

Answer (score 0):

With joins:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ResaID, StayDate, RoomCat
FROM
    StayDateInfo
WHERE
    ResaID IN
    (
        SELECT
            first.ResaID
        FROM
            StayDateInfo first
            JOIN StayDateInfo second ON 
                first.ResaID = second.ResaID
                AND first.StayDate = second.StayDate
                AND first.RoomCat != second.RoomCat
    )
```

With groupings:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT *
FROM
  StayDateInfo
WHERE
  ResaID IN
  (
    SELECT
      ResaID
    FROM
    (
      SELECT
          ResaID, StayDate, RoomCat
      FROM
          StayDateInfo
      GROUP BY
          ResaID, StayDate, RoomCat
    ) grouped
    GROUP BY
      ResaID, StayDate
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
  )
```

Comment: @user3115933 that's because the test data you provided does not have any record sets where the RoomCat values by ResaID are NOT the same for each StayDate. I adjusted that as mentioned and then tested and both of these queries work. See [this working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8635a/14).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select ResaID 
from table 
group by ResaID 
having count(distinct RoomCat) > 1
```

Comment: It only retrieves the list of ResaID. I also need the output to include the remaining 2 columns (StayDate and RoomCat)

Comment: What you are looking for is called a `join`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 declare @tableA table(ResaID INT,StayDate DATETIME,RoomCat varchar(3))

    INSERT INTO @tableA
    SELECT 100,'2018-03-01','STD'
    union all
    SELECT 100,'2018-03-02','STD'
    union all
    SELECT 100,'2018-03-03','STD'
    union all
    SELECT 101,'2018-04-15','STD'
    union all
    SELECT 101,'2018-04-16','STD'
    union all
    SELECT 101,'2018-04-17','DLX'
    union all
    SELECT 101,'2018-04-18','DLX'


    select ResaId 
    from @tableA
    Group by ResaId
    Having COUNT(DISTINCT RoomCat)=2
```